# wordpressのサイトで数10KBのCSSの読み込みに8秒から40秒もかかる理由を知りたい

Tags: php, apache, wordpress, nginx

wordpressのサイトが重たくて困っています。
Chromeのデベロッパーツールで見たところ、たかだかファイルサイズが数10KBのCSSのTTFBが8秒から40秒もかかっているようです。(下にコピペしたデベロッパーツールの結果を参照)。もっと早く(100msくらい)読み込みできそうなものなのにどうしてだろうと不思議に思っています。

ちなみに、一度ページを読み込めばブラウザのキャッシュにのるので、普通に見れる速度で読み込んでくれます。

また、このCSSが後続のロードをブロックしてるところもあるようですが、まぁそれはまたおいおい解決するとしてまずは今回相談してる問題をどうにかしたいと思っています。

#### 質問

- 何が原因で、CSSのTTFBがこんなに遅くなっているのか？
- どうすれば速くすることができるか？
- 速くするために何を調査すればいいか？

#### 環境

- AWSのt2.small
- 半年前にAWSの最新版の日本語ドキュメントに従って構築したwordpress環境
- NginxではなくてApacheを使っている(Apacheの設定の問題？)
- PHP7を利用

#### デベロッパーツールの結果

[image: developer tool]

#### 8/13 朝追記

ちなみにApacheの設定も共有しておきます。apachectl -Vで見る限りpreforkで動いてます。

StartServers       1
MinSpareServers    1
MaxSpareServers   2
ServerLimit      4
MaxClients       1
MaxRequestsPerChild  5

Comment: Apacheが原因で遅いのどうかを切り分けるために、Apacheのログに処理時間を追記することは可能ですか？http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/ja/mod/mod_log_config.html
「%D リクエストを処理するのにかかった時間、マイクロ秒単位」

Answer (score 4):

Apacheの設定値ですが、極端に 値が小さい気がします。
特に `MaxClients` はサーバーが同時に応答できる上限なので、値が 1 だと、相当遅いんじゃないかなと推測します。切り分けの意味でも、一旦デフォルトの設定値に戻してみてはどうでしょう。

あとはサーバーのログを確認するのも良いと思います。
アクセスログを見て どのくらいの同時アクセスがあったかのか、エラーのたぐいは記録されていないか、など確認してみてください。

また、AWSのインタンスサイズが t2.small ですが、これは性能が低いインスタンスクラスなので、基本的な性能不足かもしれません。AWSのCloudWatch で メトリックを確認してみると良いと思います。特に T2 インスタンスは CPUクレジットを使い切ると極端に遅くなります。

ディスク（EBS） が遅い可能性もあるので、こちらも CloudWatchで確認してみてください。汎用SSDの場合は、T2のCPU同様に、クレジットを使い切ると極端に遅くなります。

Comment: ありがとうございます！Apacheの設定をもとに戻したら無事に解決しました！